# What's the difference between ? and ! in collections like Map, List and Set?

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety

What's the difference between `?` and `!` when used in a collection in Dart?

---

Say, I have:

```dart
var list = [1, 2];
```

Now, I can either use

```dart
print(list?[0]); // prints 1
```

or

```dart
print(list![0]); // also prints 1
```

Both of them seems to do the same job, so what's the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of them seem to do the same job because your `list` is of type `List<int>` (non-nullable) and not the `List<int>?` (nullable). If your list had been of nullable type like:

```dart
List<int>? list;
```

you'd see the difference.

---

**Using`?` (Null aware operator)**

It would be safe to use `?` because in case `list` is `null`, `list?[0]` would still print `null` rather than throwing an error.

```dart
print(list?[0]); // Safe
```

or you could also use `??` to provide a default value.

```
print(list?[0] ?? -1); // Safe. Providing -1 as default value in case the list is null
```

---

**Using `!` (Bang operator)**

However, `!` throws runtime error because you're explicitly saying that your `list` is not `null` and you're downcasting it from nullable to non-nullable:

```dart
print(list![0]); // Not safe. May cause runtime error if list is null
```

This is equivalent to

```dart
print((list as List)[0]);
```